# Use cases of Covarient/Contravarient Annotations in Scala

Tags: scala

In Scala, it's possible to specify whether a function or class is covarient or contravarient in the following manner

```
class Foo[+arg] // covarient
class Bar[-arg] // contravarient
```

What are the real world uses of this feature?
I know the compiler runs checks to make sure that the stated entity is actually covarient or otherwise, but what is the benefit of even adding such annotations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest case where your probably already using it without knowing it is the scala collections.

```
class A()
class B() extends A
case class Container[T](elem : T)

val listOfA:List[A] = List[B](new B(),new B())
val containerOfA:Container[A] = Container[B](new B()) // fails
```

Comment: I think your example is wrong: `List` is covariant but that doesn't not allow you to define `:::(that: List[A]): List[A]`. The actual signature of this method is [`def :::[B >: A](prefix: List[B]): List[B]`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.11.5/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/List.scala#L125) which does not require variance on A.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine you have the following hierarchy:

```
class A
class B extends A
```

**Covariance**. Covariant type can be used as return type:

```
class Foo[+arg] { // Covariant
  def getArg(): arg = ???
}

def testCovariant(): Unit = {
  val fooB = new Foo[B]
  val foo: Foo[A] = fooB

  // returns only objects of class derived from A
  // so it is safe
  val a: A = foo.getArg()
}
```

So you can use any of `Foo[DerivedClass]`where `Foo[BaseClass]` is used, because anywhere `Foo[BaseClass].getArg` is called `BaseClass` is expected as result and any `DerivedClass` can be returned and assigned to it.

**Contravariance**. Contravariant type can be used as method parameter type:

```
class Bar[-arg] { // Contravariant
  def setArg(p: arg): Unit = ???
}

def testContravariant(): Unit = {
  val barA = new Bar[A]
  val bar: Bar[B] = barA

  // can set B to bar which is actually Bar[A]
  // but Bar[A].setArg(p: A) can accept any object 
  // of type derived from A
  // so it is safe
  bar.setArg(new B)
}
```

Again. You can use any of `Bar[DerivedClass]` where `Bar[BaseClass]` is used, because anywhere `Bar[DerivedClass].setArg(p: DerivedClass)` is called `DerivedClass` is expected as argument and any `Bar[BaseClass]` can be used in this context, because you can always pass `DerivedClass` to `Bar[BaseClass].setArg(p: BaseClass)`.